# ie8 invalid operand to 'in': object expected in gmap3 js file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, operator-keyword, jquery-gmap3

In the gmap3.js file there are lines such as

```
       if (M in arguments[L]) {
            N[M] = arguments[L][M];
            return
        }
```

In all other browsers there is no error on my console. Only in ie8

ie8 invalid operand to 'in': object expected. Seems like there is something wrong with M in arguments[L]  either the 'M' or 'arguments[L]' is causing this issue. This snippet above is part of gmap3.js file. I've tried seeing typeof and they seems correct. "M" is a string and arguments[L] is an object type.

And from microsoft's documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/9k25hbz2(v=vs.94).aspx it says in is supported so not sure whats wrong. Any help will definitely be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like `arguments[L]` is a primitive or undefined.

Comment: maybe assigning it to a variable first might help in IE? also make sure you've declared a doctype, even though it should work regardless